# c# LINQ to XML test data loading

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to set up a Test Harness and I have some data I want to include in my project in XML format and load that into the business objects in the test pre-setup method.

The class structure is

```
public class DbUserChoice 
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    } 
public class DbUserAmbition : DbUserChoice { } 
public class DbUserDiet : DbUserChoice { } 
public class DbUserEthnicity : DbUserChoice { } 
etc...
```

So there is an abstract base class DbUserChoice that is then extended by all the different types of choices a user has (15 in total). All of these except one add nothing to the class, just extending it verbatim.

The XML structure is (partial)

```
<UserChoiceOptions> 
  <UserChoice ChoiceType="DbUserAmbition"> 
    <Choice>I'm content to just sit back and enjoy life</Choice> 
    <Choice>I have a few ambitions and dreams but keep my feet on the ground</Choice> 
    <Choice>I'm quite ambitious and driven in my career and personal life</Choice> 
    <Choice>I'm extremely driven to succeed and want the very best from life</Choice> 
  </UserChoice> 
  <UserChoice ChoiceType="DbUserBodyType"> 
    <Choice Gender="M">Slim</Choice> 
    <Choice Gender="M">Athletic and toned</Choice> 
    <Choice Gender="M">A healthy medium</Choice> 
    <Choice Gender="M">Muscular</Choice> etc...
```

I want some kind of generic method that I can pass a DataType to, and it returns me an IQueryable of the choices that map to that datatype in the XML, chosen by the "ChoiceType" discriminator attribute on the UserChoice node above.

Eg

```
var ambitions = TestUtil.ReadXMLObjects<DbUserAmbition>(xmlFilePath);
```

would return me an `IQueryable<DbUserAmbition>` with the above 4 options

14 of the 15 user choice types would behave in this way. The only one different is the DbUserBodyType one also mentioned above, as you can see this has an additional attribute on each  record of Gender. This is a new property on the DbUserBodyType class, it is the only derived class that adds a new record to the base class, and this woudl also need to be popualted from that XML attribute.

I've been trying to achieve this using Linq to XML but I can't seem to quite get it right. The following code gives me a list of XElements but I can't see how to easily and cleanly translate that to a list of C# DbUserAmbition objects for example without using messy reflection.

```
var element = XElement.Load(_xmlPath);
            var typeName = typeof(T).Name;

            var nodes = from n in element.Elements("UserChoiceOptions/UserChoice/Choice")
                        where n.Parent.Attribute("ChoiceType").Value.Equals(typeName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                        select n;
```

Any advice would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can achive this by declaring a method which would parse data from xml:

```
public class DbUserChoice 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; } 

    public virtual void Parse(XElement node)
    {
        //assign properties from XElement here
        //override this method in DbUserBodyType to add additional logic
    } 
}
```

Then your query will end with:

```
return nodes.Select(n => { var x = new T(); x.Parse(n); return x; }).AsQueryable();
```

This will add a restriction `T : DbUserChoice, new()` to your generic method, but that should not be a problem